# Using Shapely to convert 2 columns to WKB

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda, shapely, wkb

I have 2 columns in a CSV called `Longitude` and `Latitude` which are being parsed using my Python AWS Lambda Code.

I am using the `shapely` module with the following code to convert the long/lats into geometry format

```
g = wkt.loads('POINT(-2.5378432182396935 55.20394960316738)')
                    new = wkb.dumps(g, hex=True, srid=4326)
                    print (new)
```

Is there a way to call the two columns so that each entry is individually given their wkb, rather than put each point in individually?

e.g.

```
g = wkt.loads('POINT('longitude' 'latitude')')
                    new = wkb.dumps(g, hex=True, srid=4326)
                    print (new)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could instantiate a `MultiPoint` object (instead of going through wkt) using lat/lon pairs:

```
from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint
from shapely import wkb

mp = MultiPoint(tuple(zip(latitude, longitude)))
mp_wkb = wkb.dumps(mp, hex=True, srid=4326)
print(mp_wkb)
```